# how to write a formula in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write a formula where the shorter the distance, the more points you get, the farther the distance, the less points

```
    fun raiting(distance: Float): Int {
    var rating = 1000
    var maxDistance = 11750F
    
    rating = if (distance > maxDistance) {
        0
    } else{
        ..
    }


    return rating
}
```

The question is how to write such a formula? Or tell me which formula to use

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There are many formulas that satisfy "the shorter the distance, the more points you get". What exactly happens in between? And yes, I know it's "you get a moderate amount of points". Exactly how should the formula behave?

Comment: it should return the number of points proportionally to distance and points

Comment: [Forum](https://www.google.com/search?q=forum+definition) and [Formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=formula+definition). You should first be able to write how to calculate each point in human language, only then you can think of coding it

Comment: sorry my mistake

Comment: The math term you're looking for is "linear interpolation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply calculate percentage of distance from max distance where 0 means 100% and *maxDistance* means 0%:

```
fun raiting(distance: Float): Int {
    var maxDistance = 11750F
    
    rating = 100 - (distance * 100 / maxDistance)


    return toInt(rating)
}
```